# SSRS multiple cascading parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have 6 cascading parameters in my report. The first is working fine, it filters the values in the second parameter, but the third doesn't filter the results and it returns all the values. Can someone guide me first how should I play with this many parameters?

Thanks in advance, Olga

Comment: Post here the code for all your parameters

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WR7ebq80 here's code for the first three parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. It was a problem with the M:N relationship between the dimensions.The problem is that all Webservices are shown because the relationship between WebService and Name isn't enforced. So I changed the With part:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS IIF([Dim Web Service Web Method].
[Web Service].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION ="All","Сите сервиси",[Dim Web 
Service Web Method].[Web Service].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION)
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS IIF(IsEmpty([Measures].[Broj 
Pristapi]),null,[Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web 
Service].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME)
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS IIF(IsEmpty([Measures].[Broj 
Pristapi]),null, [Dim Web Service Web Method].[Web 
Service].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL)
```

and then changed

```
[Dim WebService WebMethod].[Web Service].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS
```

into:

```
NONEMPTY([Dim WebService WebMethod].[Web Service].ALLMEMBERS,[Measures].[Broj Pristapi])
```